# A problem about change of variables formula in Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis

We can prove that if $g$ is strictly increasing and absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$, and $f$ is a nonnegative integrable function on $[c,d]$, where $c=g(a), d=g(b)$, then

$$
\int_c^d f(y)dy = \int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x)dx
$$

I wonder if the formula remains valid if $g$ is only increasing, not necessarily strict?

I think it is true, but I'm not quite convinced.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145485/does-the-change-of-variable-formula-require-strict-monotonicity. It is answered there.