# Relaxing the change of variable formula to increasing functions

Tags: integration, lebesgue-measure, change-of-variable

Currently, I am stuck at Problem 57 in Ch 6 of *Real Analysis, 4th Ed* by Royden. In the previous problem, I have proven that

> Let $g$ be **strictly increasing** and absolutely continuous on $[a, b]$.
> Then for any non-negative integrable $f$ over $[c,d]$,
> $$
>   \int^d _c f(y) dy = \int ^b _a f(g(x))g'(x) dx \tag{*}
> $$

The problem I am working on asked about

> Is the formula (*) true if $g$ is just **increasing**, not strictly increasing?

I know that the statement is true as it is stated in other literature. However, I cannot extend the result from strictly increasing to merely increasing $g$.

My attempts: 
Define $g_n (x) = g(x) + x/n$, where $g$ is increasing so $g_n$ is strictly increasing on  $[a, b]$. Let $f$ be a non-negative integrable function on $[c, d] = [g(a), g(b)]$. Further define
$$
  \alpha = \min\{c, c+a\} \quad \text{and} \quad \beta = \max \{ d, d + b\}
$$
and extend $f$ to $[\alpha, \beta]$ by setting $f = 0$ outside $[c, d]$. From (*), for all $n$,

\begin{align*}
  \int^{d+b/n} _{c + a/n} f(y) dy &= \int ^b _a f(g_n(x))g_n'(x) dx \\
  \implies \lim _{n \to \infty} \int^{d+b/n} _{c + a/n} f(y) dy 
    &= \lim _{n \to \infty} \int ^b _a f(g_n(x))g_n'(x) dx \\
  &= \lim _{n \to \infty} \int ^b _a f\left(g(x) + \frac{x}{n}\right)
    \left[g'(x) + \frac{1}{n}\right] dx
\end{align*}

I can show that the left hand side converges to $\int^d _c f(y) dy$. Note that
$$
  \int^{d+b/n} _{c + a/n} f(y) dy 
  = \int^{\beta} _{\alpha} f(y) \cdot \chi_{[c+a/n, d + b/n]}(y) \, dy
$$
Since $f \circ \chi_{[c+a/n, d + b/n]} \to f \circ \chi_{[c, d]}$ pointwise (or $ f \circ \chi_{(c ,d)}$), and
$$
  |f \circ \chi_{[c+a/n, d + b/n]}| \leq |f| \text{ for all $n$ on } [\alpha, \beta]
$$
so by the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem,
$$
  \lim _{n \to \infty} \int^{d+b/n} _{c + a/n} f(y) dy
  = \int _{\alpha} ^\beta f(y) \chi_{[c, d]} (y) dy 
  = \int _{d} ^c f(y) dy
$$

The *right hand side* is where I am stuck at. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145485/does-the-change-of-variable-formula-require-strict-monotonicity) is another post about a similar problem, which mentioned approximating $f$ by a continuous function, but I cannot see how using a continuous approximation helps. The best we know is that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a continuous function $h$ on $[\alpha, \beta]$ which
$$
  \int _\alpha ^\beta |f - h| < \epsilon
$$
And applying (*) on it gives
\begin{align*}
  \int _a ^b 
    \left| 
      f\left(g(x) + \frac{x}{n}\right)
      - h\left(g(x) + \frac{x}{n}\right)
    \right|
    \left[g'(x) + \frac{1}{n}\right] 
  dx
  &< \epsilon \\
  \implies 
  \left| 
    \int _a ^b 
      \left[ f\left(g(x) + \frac{x}{n}\right)
      - h\left(g(x) + \frac{x}{n}\right) \right]
    \left[g'(x) + \frac{1}{n}\right] 
  dx \right|
  &< \epsilon \\
  \implies 
  \int _a ^b 
      f\left(g(x) + \frac{x}{n}\right) \left[g'(x) + \frac{1}{n}\right] dx
  &< \epsilon
    + \int _a ^b h\left(g(x) + \frac{x}{n}\right) \left[g'(x) + \frac{1}{n}\right]  dx
\end{align*}
If *somehow* we can exchange limit on the right hand side, then as $h$ is continuous,
$$
  \lim _{n \to \infty}  
  \int _a ^b 
      f\left(g(x) + \frac{x}{n}\right) \left[g'(x) + \frac{1}{n}\right] dx
  \leq \epsilon
    + \int _a ^b h(g(x)) g'(x)  dx
$$
But the integral on the right is still far from the desired integral, which is
$$
  \int _a ^b f(g(x)) g'(x)  dx
$$
and we only have inequality instead of equality.

I have no idea how to proceed. I know that (*) can be proven without assuming $g$ is strictly increasing, but I would still like to know how to extend (*) to strictly increasing functions. Any advice would be appreciated.